# What is the probability that exactly seven staff CANNOT get a seat during lunch hour?

Tags: probability

For every lunch hour in weekdays, only $2$ out of $5$ staff can find a seat on average.  Given that one of the staff will have got a seat in this time period is independent to the other staff and all together $10$ staff will go out to have lunch. What is the probability that exactly seven staff CANNOT get a seat during lunch hour?

I thought it was $(3/5)^7(2/5)^3$, but it only means the probability that first seven staffs cannot find seat and last three can. What about other cases, e.g., the 2nd staff to the 8th staffs cannot find seat whereas the 1st, 9th and 10th staffs can? Do those cases have to be taken into count? How to count them all? I am confused.

Comment: What have you tried? What do you think you have to do?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please include your own thoughts and the effort made thus far, so that people can work with you accordingly. (Please add those in the body of the question instead of commenting.)

Answer (score 1):

We have a sequence of ten events, each with the same probability of success.  Therefore, this is a [Binomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution) problem.  The probability that exactly $k$ successes occur in $n$ trials, each with probability $p$ of success, is
$$\Pr(X = k) = \binom{n}{k}p^k(1 - p)^{n - k}$$
where $p^k$ is the probability of $k$ successes, $(1 - p)^{n - k}$ is the probability of $n - k$ failures, and $\binom{n}{k}$ is the number of ways exactly $k$ successes can occur in $n$ trials.

In your problem, we want the probability that exactly seven staff fail to get a seat.  Since the probability that a staff member succeeds in obtaining a seat is $p = 2/5$, the probability of failure is $1 - p = 1 - 2/5 = 3/5$.  If there are exactly seven failures, then there are $10 - 7 = 3$ successes.  Hence, the desired probability is 
$$\Pr(X = 3) = \binom{10}{3}\left(\frac{2}{5}\right)^3\left(\frac{3}{5}\right)^7$$